# SELinux will not disable on CentOS7

Tags: linux, centos7, selinux

I want to permanently disable right now for the short term but nothing seems to work for me

Steps I have tried

```
[root@db1e secure]# setenforce 0
[root@db1e secure]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          disabled
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      28
```

changing value in /etc/selinux/config

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=disabled 
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of three two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected. 
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

then restarting the httpd service

both still result in the same status of eabled instead of disabled which I would expect..
Any ideas?

Comment: We disable SELINUX because if your servers is not rebooted very often when it is rebooted it takes hours for the server to recover. This is not good on production servers.

Answer (score 9):

After editing file `/etc/sysconfig/selinux`, for the changes to take effect, you need to **reboot** your system to get SELinux fully disabled. You can do `setenforce 0` to get the system into "permissive" mode until a reboot occurs.

make sure you change `SELinux=enforcing` to `SELinux=disabled`

Comment: shouldn't setenforce 0 work regardless?

Comment: `setenforce 0` will set selinux to permissive mode. Disabling selinux always requires a reboot.

Comment: @guesterator_php for Disabling  SELinux you need a reboot

Comment: Why would you want to disable it if you can put it in permissive ? This is a very bad security practice.